# Buscar menor valor entre colunas

Tags: sql-server

Preciso criar uma nova coluna no SQL comparando 5 colunas diferentes e puxar sempre o menor valor entre elas diferente de 0
Não sei como colocar essa condição de diferente de 0.

```
    A.*,
    B.motiv_sucateamento
    CASE
        WHEN sulco1 > sulco2 THEN sulco2
        WHEN sulco2 > sulco3 THEN sulco3
        WHEN sulco3 > sulco4 THEN sulco4
        WHEN sulco4 > sulco5 THEN sulco5
    END AS Sulco_Ajustado
```

Comment: Veja as funções [`MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql) e [`MIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

A função que traz o menor valor de uma coluna é `MIN()`, mas ela retorna o menor valor nessa coluna para toda a tabela. No seu caso, é preciso avaliar o valor na linha e não somente a coluna inteira.

A sua ideia de usar o `CASE` é válida, porém, devido ao numero de colunas, isso pode ficar grande e difícil de ler. Isso porque, por exemplo, para a "sulco1" ser a menor, ela dever comparada com todas as outras colunas, ou seja:

```
WHEN sulco1<sulco2 
 AND sulco1<sulco2 
 AND sulco1<sulco3 
 AND sulco1<sulco4 
 AND sulco1<sulco5 THEN sulco1
```

E imagina que para selecionar a "sulcol2" precisa fazer o mesmo, logo o `CASE/WHEN` vai ficar bem longo.

Uma outra possibilidade é usar o `FROM VALUES`, que permite pegar os próprio valores da linha, seria como, se a tabela tivesse isso:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
|sulco1|sulco2|sulco3|sulco4|sulco5|
|1     |2     |3     |4     |5     |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Dizer, "pegue os valores 1,2,3,4,5 e retorne o mínimo", que ficaria assim:

```
SELECT MIN(Col) 
  FROM (VALUES (sulco1), (sulco2), (sulco3), (sulco4), (sulco5)) AS X(Col))
```

Onde `X` e `Col` são "apelidos" para a origem dos dados.

A query completa fica assim:

```
SELECT ID,
    (SELECT MIN(Col) 
       FROM (VALUES (sulco1), (sulco2), (sulco3), (sulco4), (sulco5)) AS X(Col)) AS minimo
FROM Sulco_Ajustado;
```

A titulo de conferência, podemos listar também os valores:

```
SELECT ID,
  sulco1,
  sulco2,
  sulco3,
  sulco4,
  sulco5, 
    (SELECT MIN(Col) 
       FROM (VALUES (sulco1), (sulco2), (sulco3), (sulco4), (sulco5)) AS X(Col)) AS minimo
FROM Sulco_Ajustado;
```

Em resumo, o `FROM (VALUES` pega os valores da própria linha, o `X(Col)` chama esses valores de "Col" (1,2,3,4,5 por exemplo), o `MIN(Col)` pega o menor valor entre eles.

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e23779/7)

Comment: Finalmente a Micro$oft implementou as funções LEAST() e GREATEST(), que facilitam a solução de casos como o proposto na pergunta. Entretanto, está disponível somente a partir da versão 2022 do SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Essa foi a solução que eu encontrei

```
SELECT A.*,
    B.motiv_sucateamento,
    C.sulco_ajustado,
    CASE
        WHEN status_ativo = 0 THEN 'Pronto para uso'
        WHEN status_ativo = 1 THEN 'Instalado'
        WHEN status_ativo = 2 THEN 'Sucata'
        WHEN status_ativo = 3 THEN 'Aguardando devolução'
        WHEN status_ativo = 4 THEN 'Aguardando retirada'
        WHEN status_ativo = 5 THEN 'Aguardando oficina'
        WHEN status_ativo = 6 THEN 'Vendido'
        ELSE 'Status desconhecido'
        END AS Status_Ajustado
FROM _0032ControleDePneusAuxiliar AS A
LEFT JOIN _0032ControleDePneusBpm AS B
ON A.cd_pneu = B.cod_pneu_selecionado
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
                MIN(D) sulco_ajustado
            FROM (VALUES
                    (REPLACE(sulco1,'0.00','99.00')),
                    (REPLACE(sulco2,'0.00','99.00')),
                    (REPLACE(sulco3,'0.00','99.00')), 
                    (REPLACE(sulco4,'0.00','99.00')),
                    (REPLACE(sulco5,'0.00','99.00')))
                AS E(D)) C
```